# uibarbuttonitem tint color is not white, when i set it to be

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uibarbuttonitem

I have this in my app delegate (iOS7):

`self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

But somehow the color of a uibarnavigationitem (system default add icon) is setting itself to black, all other items are white. Though when i reset the iPhone simulator this add icon is white, on re-run of app, it goes black.

This guy's tint color is set to default in attribute inspector. and nowhere in code I have opted to make it black.

Anything I am doing wrong in app delegate?

Answer (score 5):

You should set the tint of the navigation bar (or toolbar) instead of individual button items.

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

The result of the above looks like this:

[image: White on red navigation bar]

Answer (score 4):

You should use appearance method here:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Should fix your tint color.

Comment: I tried it, its fixing the issue, mind explaining why the window tint din do the trick? I mean its the daddy of all !

Comment: UIBarButtonItem isn't a view (it's a data object) so it won't inherit the window's tint color.